# Best practices of accessing a core data database in different classes

Tags: ios, core-data

As of the moment, I have three classes that each have instances of `UIManagedDocument`. I don't know if this is a good approach. Yet I'm quite curious what is the best practice for accessing a UIManagedDocument. Or perhaps is there any way to "share" it between different classes so that I won't need to have `UIManagedDocument` instances for each class that I have right now.

I've been through this [WWDC 2010 Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), under Mastering Core Data and went through its PDF slides yet I don't seem to find anything related or I'm just missing something.

Please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from this blog by Justin Driscoll. So basically, here a new class is being created that handles and provides a convenient interface to the managed document.

You can access it [here](http://adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html).